# CSS background-image fade transition works only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-transitions

**HTML:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#intro"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-custom .nav li a.navbar-brand {
    width: 70px;
    height: 62px;
    background: url(myimg.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 70px 62px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a.navbar-brand:hover {
    background: url(myimghover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

The hover effect works fine in every browser, but the transition effect works in Google Chrome only and I really can't explain why. I've already tried using sprite images and pseudo-element hover, but my images have a transparent background so, on hover, the "bottom" image remains partially visible. Any idea?

Thank you in advance.
Regards,
J.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate background-image. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: Then my only option is to use "img src" within the HTML and animate images directly, that is exactly what I wanted to avoid... :-(

Comment: I don't get it, you really need the transition? or you just want to change the image on hover?

Comment: I really need the transition, hover is fine.